# Wordpress CPT attachment save to separate folder

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to make a Custom Post Type (CPT) plugin. I am using bellow code to save the attachment and it works perfect but my question is how can I save this attachment to a separate folder other than the `wp-content` or somewhere new place in WordPress directory.

For Example :
now it save in 
`wp-content/uploads/2018/04` folder

But I want 
`wp-content/uploads/myfile` folder

```
function save_custom_meta_data($id) {

    /* --- security verification --- */
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_custom_attachment_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return $id;
    } // end if

    if('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
      if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
        return $id;
      } // end if
    } else {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
            return $id;
        } // end if
    } // end if
    /* - end security verification - */

    // Make sure the file array isn't empty
    if(!empty($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'])) {

        // Setup the array of supported file types. In this case, it's just PDF.
        $supported_types = array('application/pdf');

        // Get the file type of the upload
        $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name']));
        $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

        // Check if the type is supported. If not, throw an error.
        if(in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)) {

            // Use the WordPress API to upload the file
            $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['wp_custom_attachment']['tmp_name']));

            if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
                wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
            } else {
                add_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);
                update_post_meta($id, 'wp_custom_attachment', $upload);     
            } // end if/else

        } else {
            wp_die("The file type that you've uploaded is not a PDF.");
        } // end if/else

    } // end if

} // end save_custom_meta_data
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data');
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use 2 filter to change directly for your custom post to handle uploads.

Change `YOUR_CPT` and `YOUR_DIR` to your desired directory

According to DOCS

[**wp_handle_upload_prefilter**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter)

> When you upload Media from your WordPress admin dashboard,
>   wp_handle_upload is called once for each file the user specified.
>   wp_handle_upload_prefilter is an admin filter that is called by the
>   wp_handle_upload function. The single parameter, $file, represent a
>   single element of the $_FILES array. The wp_handle_upload_prefilter
>   provides you with an opportunity to examine or alter the filename
>   before the file is moved to its final location.

AND [**upload_dir**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir)

> This hook allows you to change the directory where files are uploaded
>   to. The keys and values in the array are used by the wp_upload_dir
>   function in wordpress core, which is doing the work.

Code to use:

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_pre_upload' );
function my_pre_upload( $file ) {
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_custom_upload_dir' );
    return $file;
}

function my_custom_upload_dir( $param ) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
    $parent = get_post( $id )->post_parent;
    if( "YOUR_CPT" == get_post_type( $id ) || "YOUR_CPT" == get_post_type( $parent ) ) {
        $mydir         = '/YOUR_DIR';
        $param['path'] = $param['basedir'] . $mydir;
        $param['url']  = $param['baseurl'] . $mydir;
    }
    return $param;
}
```

Also you can read about this [**article**](http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/03/how-to-change-upload-folder-url-for-every-uploads-in-wordpress/)